# What flag for an irrelevant comment?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I asked [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245392/do-rails-join-models-get-controllers) and one of the comments has nothing to do with the question.  It's not "wrong" (in the sense of having incorrect information), it just is totally irrelevant to the question being asked.

I want to flag for removal to clean up the site, but I'm not sure which flag is appropriate.  "Not Constructive" is, I thought, meant for comments that are joking around or being insulting.  "Obsolete" seems wrong because the comment wasn't *ever* relevant, so it didn't stop at some point.

Which flag is appropriate in this situation?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78457/should-all-irrelevant-comments-be-flagged-as-noise

Comment: That question is about "comments that no longer make sense".  What about comments that never made sense?

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question, that's why I left it as a comment. Still, it's often hard to go wrong with "too chatty"

Comment: Also "Not Constructive" is a good option i think.  It implies the comment adds nothing of value to the question, answer or conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the exception of the spam flag, I wouldn't worry much about picking the correct comment flag. When in doubt, "too chatty" is usually the better option.

If you really feel none of the predefined flags describe the issue, you always have the option of telling us exactly what's going on in a custom flag (the "other..." option).